# Calculation with "+" and "-"

Tags: java

I want to create a program in java that accepts value and does mathematical operations with the given values.

I tried it but it only works for one operator (i.e only addition or only subtraction works), when operators are mixed (i.e 10+20-5) the first operator gets replaced by the new one. I would like to find the error in my code but an alternative solution would also suffice. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;    
public class Calculation {
            static double total;
            public static void main(String args) {
    
            double number;
            String currentOperator="";
    
            int num=0;
            boolean exitCondition=!false;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
            while(exitCondition) {
    
                System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
                number = input.nextDouble();
                num++;
                System.out.print("Enter an operator: ");
                String operator = input.next();
    
                if(operator.equals("+")||operator.equals("-")) {
                //To save the operator so that it doesn't get replaced.
                    currentOperator = operator;
    
                }
    
                switch (operator){
                    case "+":{
    
                            total+=number;
                            System.out.println("CURRENT TOTAL:"+total);
                            break;
                    }
    
                    case "-": {
                            if(num==1)
                                total=number;
                            else
                                total -= number;
                            System.out.println("CURRENT TOTAL:" + total);
                            break;
                    }
    
                    case "=": {
    
                        if(currentOperator.equals("+")){
    
                            total+=number;
                            System.out.println("Total is:" + total);
                            exitCondition=!true;
    
                        }
    
                        else if(currentOperator.equals("-")){
    
                            total-=number;
                            System.out.println("Total is:" + total);
                            exitCondition=!true;
    
                  }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have some logic issues.  For example, when the operator is '-' you always subtract, but that operator would be for the next number entered.  You would need to look at the previous operator to know if the current number is added or subtracted, but right now you overwrite the previous one with the current one - maybe try moving the setting of currentOperator to after the switch statement and using currentOperator to know whether to add or subtract.

Comment: I wish that when questioners put code they would read [MRE]. The code should include all the relevant import statements and the public static void main() method. This would make it easy to copy into a debugger and help answer the question.

Comment: @NomadMaker thanks for the tip, I added the import statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input = 10+20-5

Starting Conditions:

- Total = 0
- Current Operator = ""
- Operator = unknown
- Number = unknown

First time through loop:

- number = 10
- operator = +
- set total = 0+10
- set current operator = +

Second time through loop:

- number = 20
- operator = -
- set total = 10-20
- set current operator = -

etc...

You are using the left hand side of the operator to modify total, as opposed to right hand side...

Consider reading input into 2 arrays one for operators and one for values

```
//Pseudocode

/*
Validate that value array size = operator array size + 1
Initialize total to be first value in value array
remove that value from the front of the value array

Start Loop
    read operator at front of operator array
    remove operator from front of the operator array
    read number from front of value array
    remove number from front of value array
    set total = total <switch on operator> number
End Loop

Output total
*/
```

The reason I recommend this approach as opposed to what you have is that if you are calculating as you parse then you are locked in to a left -> right calculation....which doesn't allow for order of operations as you expand your operator set...   if you populate arrays and then iterate through, then the calculation is based on the order of things in the array, not the order in the original string...  which means you can parse the string first to find stuff inside parenthesis, with exponents, multiply/divide vs add/subtract, etc... and then populate your array accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you should get the operator before the operand.
The first thing you have to do before the loop is taking the first input and assigning it to the total.
After that, in the loop, you should invert the inputs and be sure of getting another operand only if the operator isn't '='.

```
System.out.print("Enter an operator: ");
String operator = input.next();

if(!operator.equals("=")){
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
number = input.nextDouble();
}
```

You won't need the variable `num` by doing this, and neither the control in the operation of subtraction.
In case the operator is '=' you will only need to print the total and not to make other controls or operations.

Comment: You are comparing a `String` to a `char`, that wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop inside the while loop and doing the operation right after taking the inputs while assigning the inputs to an array solves the problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String operator="+";
        double total=0;
        double arr[] = new double[2];
        boolean noExit=true;
    
        while(noExit) {
            
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Java Calculator!");
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; ) {
                System.out.print("Enter number: ");
                arr[i] = input.nextDouble();
    
                switch(operator){
                    case "+":
                        total+=arr[i];
                        System.out.println("Current Total: "+total);
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        total-=arr[i];
                        System.out.println("Current Total: "+total);
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        total*=arr[i];
                        System.out.println("Current Total: "+total);
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        total/=arr[i];
                        System.out.println("Current Total: "+total);
                        break;
                }
    
    
    
    
                System.out.print("Enter an operand (+,-,*,/,=): ");
                operator = input.next();
                
                if(operator.equals("=")){
                    System.out.println("\nTotal is: "+total);
                    noExit=false;
                    break;
                }
    
    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```